# Counting columns that match between several data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, data-manipulation

I have several data frames which have some columns that match (in name) and I want to know how many. I'm now using this function to merge them:

```
dflist <- list(d1, d2)
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), dflist, accumulate=FALSE)
```

But I don't know how many matched until I view it. Alternatively, I would like to drop the columns that don't match instead of filling in with NAs.

Edit, added example:

```
d1 = mtcars
d2 = mtcars[, 1:4]
d3 = mtcars[, 3:5]
dflist = list(d1,d2,d3)

dflist <- list(d1, d2)
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), dflist, accumulate=FALSE
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please make sure to provide reproducible examples and expected output so it's easier for others to help you. Regarding your question, using `Reduce` is correct, but you can easily get the common fields via the function `intersect`. So something like `Reduce(function(...)intersect(names(...)), list(your_dataframes))` should give you the common columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
d1 = mtcars
d2 = mtcars[, 1:4]
d3 = mtcars[, 3:5]
dflist = list(d1,d2,d3)
```

Now to get the matching column names across the list of df's:

```
Reduce(intersect, lapply(dflist, names))
# [1] "disp" "hp"
```

You can then continue your merge-process with only the selected common columns, for example using:

```
common_cols = Reduce(intersect, lapply(dflist, names))

Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), 
       lapply(dflist, function(x) x[, common_cols, drop=FALSE]))
```